# node.js db.query ends up with error if variable is inserted in SQL string statement

Tags: sql, node.js

Using https://github.com/felixfbecker/node-sql-template-strings in node.js to create an SQL statement but db.query ends up with error : error":"Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY '

baseQuery ->

```
SELECT 
    col1, col2, 
    SUM(totalcount) AS total, SUM(failedcount) AS count 
FROM 
    table1 
WHERE 
    col3 BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL ? AND NOW() 
GROUP BY 
    col1, col2
```

Here value after INTERVAL is parameterised.

Comment: What is the value you provide for the parameter? First hardcode that value into the query string and verify that the SQL query syntax is correct.

Comment: Are you sure this query is correct? I think there should be col2 in the end after the `,`

Can you please try this?

`SELECT col1,col2,SUM(totalcount) as total,SUM(failedcount) as count FROM table1 WHERE col3 BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL ? AND NOW() GROUP BY col1,col2`

Comment: @UdithGunaratna , harcoded value works fine, i missed specifying col2 in group by. only issue is with parameterized value.